# How to get the position of a string array element that contains a certain letter

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, split

I'm working on an application where the user will input dash separated values into a textbox,  the textbox value is put into a string array, split by "-". I need to search through this array and get the position of the element that contains the letter "q".

There could be 6 different possible inputs into this textbox, Input examples would be:

- "292"
- "292-0"
- "292-0-10"
- "292-q10"
- "292-0-q10"
- "292-0-10-q10"

I'm splitting the textbox value by "-". Code is: `string[] arrayJobSuffix = txtBFSJob.Text.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 5);`

Now I need to search through this arrayJobSuffix array and find the position of the element that contains "q".

Example, assuming the first element in the array is 0 then:

1. If value in textbox was "292", "292-0" or "292-0-10", return -1 or something indication "q" is not present.
2. If value in textbox was "292-q10", return 1
3. If value in textbox was "292-0-q10", return 2
4. If value in textbox was "292-0-10-q10", return 3 and etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it using various ways for example:

```
txtBFSJob.Text.Split('-')
.Select((x,idx) => new { x, idx })
.First(c => c.x.Contains("q")).idx;
```

Or:

```
var parts = txtBFSJob.Text.Split('-');

int index = Array.IndexOf(parts, parts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("q"));
```

First solution will throw exception if it can't find any result that contains `"q"`

Second solution won't throw exception it will just return `-1`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, for the first solution I get the following error: _Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement_ and for the second solution I get error: _No overload for method 'First' takes 2 arguments_

Comment: Never mind, I goofed on the second solution. It works perfectly now. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string.contains()` method in a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayJobSuffix.Length; i++)
{
    if (arrayJobSuffix[i].contains("q"))
        return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int GetSearchStringIndex(string[] inputs, char searchString){
    int index = -1;
    int len = inputs.Length;
    for(int i=0; i<len ; i++){
        foreach(char c in inputs[i]){
            if(c==searchString){
                index=i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}

public static int GetSearchStringIndex(string[] inputs, string searchString){
    int index = -1;
    int len = inputs.Length;
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        if(inputs[i].Contains(searchString)){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```